# How do I sign my app bundle for Google play?

Tags: android, google-play, google-console-developer

I am new to Android development, I just created a free little app that I would like to publish on the Google Play Store. I already uploaded my  app bundle to the developer console, but I lack the signing process. I think the missing step is, from the developers tutorial, this one:

$ keytool -export -rfc
  -keystore your-upload-keystore.jks
  -alias upload-alias
  -file output_upload_certificate.pem

What should I replace "your-upload-keystore.jks", "upload-alias", and "output_upload_certificate.pem" with? Furthermore, I haven't an .pem certificate, I just have the two .der certificates: deployment and upload that Google sent me. Am I missing something? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't already have a Keystore, you should go in Android Studio and go in Build > Generate Signed Apk or Bundle and click on "Create new", Write a name an alias and everything that the Keystore needs.

**IMPORTANT**: Don't forget to save your alias name and password somewhere, because you'll need theese things next time you'll use the Keystore.

**IMPORTANT2**: Once you signed the App, do a backup of the keystore, it's very important and if you lose it, you will not be able to update your own app, because Google App Store will request the same Keystore that you used for the first upload of your App, so don't forget, do a multiple backup and remember the alias and password.

If you have already a Keystore you should just select the Keystore instead creating a new one and insert the Alias Key and the Password, that's all!

Comment: Thank you. The App is already signed, but what should I do now? Should I do that from the Google Console or should I launch the keytool command from the Terminal? The keystore's name is same with the .jks extension?

Comment: If you have the App signed and this is the first time that you upload the App, you don't need to do anything of what you wrote, and yes the .jks file is the keystore!

Answer (score 2):

The tools you need is just right on your IDE.

There are many ways you can generate a signed apk or bundle. what i prefer is Studio one.

Here is how you can generate one.

Step one :

[image]

Step Two :

[image]

Step Three:

[image]

if you have your keystore generated already then you can select one by clicking on **choose existing** button and move ahead if you don't have this generated then you can just create a brand new by clicking on **create new** button.

if everything is right then you can see your app bundle generated in `app/release`

Comment: Thank you. Sure, I see the app bundle generated in app/release, the problem is that the bundle is still a "draft" in the Console, I mean, the "start implementation for production" button, at the bottom, is deactivated. What is missing?

Comment: Make sure you have to fill all the details in other tabs